# Python middle backend developer, task for an applicant (source link)

Tags: python

I asked a code review [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/257159/222384) and this is the source link for that question (I could post this question on google drive or other web drive, but I think all parts of the "stack exchange" sites should be stored on "stack exchange" servers) ...
The task is posted "as is."

**The Story**

In US, taxes are often complex and require many different PDF forms and posted informational
notices. IRS service keeps records of the current tax year's forms and historical forms going back
many years online on [irs.gov](https://irs.gov).

For this challenge you must write two different utilities for searching IRS tax forms:

• Taking a list of tax form names (ex: "Form W-2", "Form 1095-C"), search the website and
return some informational results. Specifically, you must return the "Product Number", the
"Title", and the maximum and minimum years the form is available for download.

The results should be returned as json, in the format of the following example:

```
[
{
"form_number": "Form W-2",
"form_title": "Wage and Tax Statement (Info Copy Only)",
"min_year": 1954,
"max_year": 2021
}
...
]
```

• Taking a tax form name (ex: "Form W-2") and a range of years (inclusive, 2018-2020 should
fetch three years), download all PDFs available within that range. The downloaded PDFs
should be downloaded to a subdirectory under your script's main directory with the name of
the form, and the file name should be the "Form Name - Year" (ex: Form W-2/Form W-2 -
2020.pdf ).

**Requirements**

The challenge must be written in Python 3 and can use any publicly available library. If you use any
non-standard libraries, you MUST include a standard pip-compatible "requirements.txt" file outlining
every requirement needed to run your script(s).
You may use any method for taking input and returning required output from your script (command
line arguments, command line input, files, etc.)
You must include a README.txt file explaining which specific version of Python is used (ex: Python
3.8.0), how to properly run your script (including how it takes input parameters and how it outputs
JSON for part 1.) Also, feel free to use this README.txt to add any additional info you'd like to share
about your script or any feedback on the challenge itself

P.S. To conform with a stack overflow rules I will publish an my currently solution.

```
import asyncio
import aiofiles
from aiohttp import ClientSession as aiohttp_ClientSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path as pathlib_Path
from json import dumps as json_dumps
from loguru import logger
from sys import platform as sys_platform

# # # HARDCODED # # #
MIN_YEAR = 2018
MAX_YEAR = 2020


def is_key_in_dict(dict_key: str, array: list):
    for i, dict_ in enumerate(array):
        if dict_['form_number'] == dict_key:
            return i


async def load_page(url: str, session, ):
    async with session.get(url=url, ) as resp:
        if 200 <= resp.status <= 299:
            return await resp.read()
        else:
            logger.error(f'Can not access a page, returned status code: {resp.status_code}')


async def parse_page_forms_json(rows: list) -> list[str]:  # Every page contain set of forms
    page_forms = []
    for row in rows:
        try:
            form_number = row.findChild(['LeftCellSpacer', 'a']).string.split(' (', 1)[0]  # split to remove non eng ver
            current_year = int(row.find(name='td', attrs={'class': 'EndCellSpacer'}).string.strip())
            index = is_key_in_dict(dict_key=form_number, array=page_forms)
            if index is None:
                page_forms.append({
                    'form_number': form_number,  # Title in reality
                    'form_title': row.find(name='td', attrs={'class': 'MiddleCellSpacer'}).string.strip(),
                    'min_year': current_year,
                    'max_year': current_year,
                })
            else:  # If exists - modify form
                if page_forms[index]['min_year'] > current_year:
                    page_forms[index]['min_year'] = current_year
                elif page_forms[index]['max_year'] < current_year:
                    page_forms[index]['max_year'] = current_year
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'Error: {e}')
    return [json_dumps(page_form) for page_form in page_forms]  # What to do whit this data?


async def save_page_form_pdf(rows, session):
    for row in rows:
        try:
            current_year = int(row.find(name='td', attrs={'class': 'EndCellSpacer'}).string.strip())
            form_number_elem = row.findChild(['LeftCellSpacer', 'a'])  # link and name
            form_number = form_number_elem.string.split(' (', 1)[0]  # split to remove non eng ver
            if MIN_YEAR <= current_year <= MAX_YEAR:
                resp = await load_page(url=form_number_elem.attrs['href'], session=session)
                # See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir
                pathlib_Path(form_number).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # exist_ok - skip FileExistsError
                filename = f"{form_number}/{form_number}_{current_year}.pdf"
                async with aiofiles.open(file=filename, mode='wb') as f:
                    await f.write(resp)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'Can not save file, error: {e}')


async def main():
    async with aiohttp_ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        pagination = 0
        while 1:
            url = (f'https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html?'
                   f'indexOfFirstRow={pagination}&'
                   f'sortColumn=sortOrder&'
                   f'value=&criteria=&'
                   f'resultsPerPage=200&'
                   f'isDescending=false')
            page = await load_page(url=url, session=session)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
            table = soup.find(name='table', attrs={'class': 'picklist-dataTable'})  # Target
            rows = table.find_all(name='tr')[1:]  # [1:] - Just wrong HTML
            if rows:
                tasks.append(await parse_page_forms_json(rows=rows))  # Task 1
                tasks.append(await save_page_form_pdf(rows=rows, session=session))  # Task 2
                pagination += 200
            else:  # Stop pagination
                break
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # See https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914#issuecomment-622586610 (exit code is 0, but error is exists)
    if sys_platform.startswith('win'):
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    logger.add('errors.txt', level='ERROR', rotation="30 days", backtrace=True)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You need to `await` async functions

Comment: While I don't think this is a bad idea, it doesn't really fit what SO does. Perhaps there is [another site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) that is a better fit, or you might consider starting one of you your own via [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I will give a link to a code review within 40 minutes (questions limit of "stack exchange")

Comment: In any event, this is hardly a minimal example showing the problem.  Whatever your problem with line 36 is surely doesn't need all of this code nor all of the explanation to show it.